# BibTeX Style for Electronic Letters Magazine

Tags: bibtex

Does anyone know a BibTeX style (`bst`) suitable to be used in the Electronic Letters Magazine?

I have the LaTeX template from here: http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/el/author-guide, but not the BibTeX style.

And I am not quite sure if the `IEEEtran` is suitable for that.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to remove the biblatex tag if you are looking for a pure bibtex solution, which seems to be the case?

Comment: Well I was thinking that was also suitable for BibLateX. But since not all systems have BibLaTeX (which might be also the case of the magazine), probably you are right.

Comment: @Mico do you suggest any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From checking the journal's presentation guide and judging by the paucity of bibliography-related information in `sample.tex` (the file that comes with the class file), I'd say you're safe -- for the purpose of submitting a manuscript to the journal -- using just about any bibliography style that (a) produces numeric-style citation call-outs and (b) abbreviates authors' first and middle names down to the initials. You could use a bib style such as `apalike`, or any one of the `IEEE` styles. If you use the `natbib` citation management package, be sure to load it with the option `numbers`; `natbib`'s default style for citation call-outs is `authoryear`.

If and when your paper is accepted for publication, you'll hopefully get some real instructions regarding how the bibliography should be formatted.